# Installing and accessing Clam AV Antivirus in 12.04

Tags: clamav

I have installed Clam AV antivirus for Ubuntu. I read [this Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1638141)

As per the instructions there I ran `sudo apt-get install clamav`, but the apapplication is not visible in my dashboard.

I am very new to Linux

How can I see the GUI of ClamAV and access it or uninstall it?

Or, can anybody suggest an effective open source antivirus application for Ubuntu?

Comment: ClamAV doesn't come with a GUI by default. For a GUI,  see the **Graphical user interface** section of [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/250291/176889).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all note that you don't need antivirus for linux. Check the answer for this question [Linux Anti-Virus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399351/linux-anti-virus/399366#399366)

---

For clamav  it comes with noGUI but to do it in command line :

To Install Clamav

```
sudo apt-get install clamav
```

To update pattern files

```
sudo freshclam
```

To scan all your filesystem and remove infected files

```
sudo clamscan --infected --remove --recursive /
```

To download test virus

```
wget http://www.eicar.org/download/eicar.com
```

To uninstall

```
sudo apt-get remove clamav
```

But you can use a frontend GUI that works with calmav called AntiVirus Scanner(avscan). you can download from [here](http://freecode.com/projects/avscan).

Moreover there are many GUI frontends for calmav. you can check this menu [here](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/download/third-party-tools/3rdparty-gui/) and choose one of them but i advise you by the one above(avscan)

If you want to use other GUI i advise to use [comodo](http://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/antivirus-for-linux.php).Comodo has a free, modern, easy to use anti-virus program for various GNU/Linux distributions including Ubuntu 12.04.x.y 32 and 64 bit LTS. The graphical user interface is easy to learn how to use.

Comment: Thanks Maythux, if i install avscan, do i have to uninstall clam av. if so please help how to uninstall it.

Comment: @Auro_user239244 You don't have to uninstall calmav since avscan is just a GUI frontend and it cant standalone. It uses calmav. I also stated in my answer how to uninstall check it